# Session timeout in Spring Security Java configuration

Tags: spring-security, session-timeout

I put session time out in deployment descriptor file but it is not working and I am using Spring Security. Is anything need to configure in Spring Security.

This is the configuration in Spring Security:

```java
http.sessionManagement()
    .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalid=1")
    .maximumSessions(1)
        .expiredUrl("/login?time=1")
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

This is in deployment descriptor:

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: what exactly its happening now?? after one minute are you still able to access the app or its not redirecting to `login?time=1`

Comment: Thankyou @PrasannaKumar , that is working now , actually i didn' t changed anything.

Comment: Now the problem with ajax request, if i send any ajax request after session expired , it is not navigating to login page at the same time request is not going to the server.How to deal with ajax requests after session expired ?